# sbt test a single directory

Tags: playframework, sbt

I am using Play framework. I have multiple scala directories under test and some of them fail to compile.  So I want to compile/test a single directory under test. 
For example say I have a test directory and underneath I have test/dir1, test/dir2 ..
dir1 has issues and I don't want to compile/run dir1 classes, just compile/run dir2 classes
If I use - > sbt test:testOnly dir2/.. 
sbt is also compiling dir1 classes which fail.
Is there a way to tell sbt to ignore dir1 directory and just test dir2 classes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can pattern match them:

`sbt testOnly *.dir2.*`

If you have sub-projects:

`sbt server/testOnly *.dir2.*`

Here you have sbt sub-project called server

To find out your subprojects, use:

`sbt projects`

Comment: I did that - in fact used the exact class as well - what I have is this in my code.  sbt "; project ws ; test:testOnly returns.LosCoyotesReturnsSpec". However sbt is compiing all classes in ws directory.

Comment: Add your project structure and all your taken steps to your question. Use code style (`code..`)

Comment: With your example the sbt call should be: `sbt ws/testOnly *.dir2.*`

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is just to exclude the problematic tests:

With Scala Test you can **exclude** tests, when you put `@DoNotDiscover`to a test class,like:

```
import org.scalatest.DoNotDiscover

@DoNotDiscover
class AdaptersExtensionsTest extends UnitTest {
..
}
```

Be aware that this is risky as you may forget about these tests.

Better I think is to ignore tests. In Scala Test depending on your testing flavor you can ignore single or group of tests ([check the documentation](http://www.scalatest.org)). Here an example for `FeatureSpec`:

```
 ignore(s"Get the OpeningHours from the DataCore webservice.") {
    scenario("Get the OpeningHours for the Center.") {
      Given("The Service is correctly configured.")
      ...
      When("calling the Service.")
      ...
      Then("The OpeningHours have exactly 7 OpeningHour (for each day).")
        assert(...)
      }
    }
```

This is better as when running the tests you will get warnings for all ignored tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it the way you describe, but you have two options:

- If you *systematically* want to compile and test those directories separately, you have to put them in separate sbt subprojects.
- And if you want to exclude just some sources from compilation *temporarily* while you develop another part of the application, you can do that with the `excludeFilter in unmanagedSources` sbt key. Like this:

  ```
  excludeFilter in unmanagedSources ~= { _ ||  "*/dir2/*" }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Guess there is no easy way. I spilt up the projects so I can compile them separately.

Answer (score 0):

with `sbt 1.7.1` you can call at the root of the project:

```
sbt "Test / testOnly *your-directory*"
```

or

```
sbt "Test / test/testOnly *dir2*"
```